# find text contained in a div and get its child checkbox ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I`m trying to write a script that gets the ID from a checkbox element and do something with it. The problem is that I can not target the checkboxes by value since its generated from mysql query.

Here is how the html for the checkboxes looks like :

```
<div class="cat_checkbox cat_unchecked">
     <input id="r_c136" type="checkbox" value="36" name="r_c1[]">
     Sample
</div>
<div class="cat_checkbox cat_unchecked">
     <input id="r_c131" type="checkbox" value="31" name="r_c1[]">
     Text1
</div>
```

And here is the code I managed to write (I`m still learning java script and jQquery).
What I am trying to do is to tell js to select the  that contains "Text1" and find the checkbox inside it, get its  id and then add checked prop to the item.

But instead it selects the first div finds the checkbox inside and checks it no matter the value inside.

```
 $( "#click" ).click(function() {


        if ($( "div:contains('Text1')" ))
                        {
                        id = $("div:contains('Text1')").find("input[type='checkbox']").attr("id")+"";
                        alert(id);

                        $("#"+id).prop("checked", !($("#"+id)).is(':checked'));
                        }

        });
       });
```

Any help will be aprciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use `$("div:contains('Text1')").length` instead of `$("div:contains('Text1')")`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("div:contains('Text1')").length` instead of `$("div:contains('Text1')")`

<s>Change Your code as</s>

```
$("#click").click(function () {
    if($("div:contains('Text1')").length) {
        var checkbox = $("div:contains('Text1')").find("input[type='checkbox']"); //Find Checkbox here
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.is(':checked'));
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TVfhv/)

Change your code as

```
$("#click").click(function () {
    var checkbox = $("div:contains('Text1')").find("input[type='checkbox']");
    if (checkbox.length) {
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.is(':checked'));
    }
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TVfhv/1/)

Comment: Yes, or simply $("div:contains('Text1') input[type='checkbox']")

Comment: For some reason when I use this code and the statement is true : "div:contains('Text1') It selects all my checkboxes.

Comment: @Newbie, What do you mean by `the statement is true`

Comment: sorry accdently clicked enter the statement is true : "div:contains('Text1') It selects all my checkboxes. I mean if it finds a match in any div it checks  all the text boxes in the form. Thats why I was wondering if its posible to extract the ID.

Comment: @Newbie, You can use `checkbox.attr("id")`